Some compilers print an error, some don't in C
The code below is a copy of an online resource about nested structure in C.
The program defines 2 structures, "Organisation" and "Employee", then in main function an object of "Organisation" will be created.
The comment says the program will cause an error. In fact, compilers I found online print an error on the line as expected, saying "warning: declaration does not declare anything" but still displaying the output.
but GCC compiler interprets the lines and define another non-nested structure called "Employee" even though its inside the definition of the structure "Organisation".
So, I'd like to know the logic behind it. Thank you in advance!
#include <stdio.h> 

// Declaration of the outer 
// structure 
struct Organisation 
{ 
    char organisation_name[20]; 
    char org_number[20]; 
    
    // Declaration of the employee 
    // structure 
    struct Employee 
    { 
        int employee_id; 
        char name[20]; 
        int salary; 
    
        // **This line will cause error because **
        // datatype struct Employee is present, but Structure variable is missing. 
    }; 
}; 

//continues

Turned out if I compile the program with the command gcc test.c -ansi -pedantic, it shows warning: ISO C90 doesn't support unnamed structs/unions [-Wpedantic] };, meaning the program can execute without errors, but it might be against some standard, which some compilers don't allow and gcc without options allows?

No compilers throw an error. Exceptions are thrown. Errors are printed. Don't misuse standard terminology.

"and still displaying the output." - What output?

geeksforgeeks is, in my experience, not a good reference for C or C++ (or anything else). That article you point to starts with invalid syntax, an example that seems correct is listed further down.

What is the purpose of struct Employee? Do you want that as a nested structure in Organisation? If so, the instance of it needs a name. Even if that solves the compilation error, it looks like the design is flawed. Every Organization should most probably be capable of having any number of Employees, not exactly one. Draw this relation on paper before starting to program.

@klutt
Whatever related to the struct such as sizeof(organisation) or access values stored after creating an object. I mean it's working well. Sorry for my bad question and thank you for your comment!

@taku1029 What does "it's working well" mean? Does every Organisation have exactly one Employee?

@TedLyngmo Hello! I know the its a poor design, but it's just an example of nested structure that i found online, i'll appreciate it if you don't too much care about it.
"working well" means no warning & error messages were shown when compiled. I could've described precisely. Thank you!

All compilers have a default setting that isn't 100% standards compliant, because that allows some old (possibly pre-standard) programs to compile (which avoids "This has always worked, why is the compiler complaining now?!"). If you want it to be stricter, you just have to ask for that, like -pedantic-errors.

Anonymous struct is "C11" (these are 2 digit years, so it's later than "C90" which is what your compiler refers to in the warning). In addition to standards, compilers have always supported stuff regardless of standards, so it might or might not work on compilers even if they don't claim to be C11. "warning: declaration does not declare anything" does not all sound like supporting the feature, though.

@BoP Your explanation is very easy to understand to me as a beginner! Thanks a lot!

@ChristianStieber I didn't know the concept of Anonymous Union and Structures! Now I can keep the research smoothly. Also detailed small desctription helped me a lot. Thas't so kind of you!

This code violates the constraint in C 2018 6.7.2.1 2:

A struct-declaration that does not declare an anonymous structure or anonymous union shall contain a struct-declarator-list.

Specifically, this means that in the grammar rule in 6.7.2.1 1 that says a struct-declaration may be ”specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-listopt ;”, that either this is an anonymous structure or union or the struct-declarator-list is not optional. As we will see below, this means each struct-declaration inside the structure definition declares either an anonymous union or structure, a named member, or an anonymous bit-field.
To understand this, we start by recognizing that struct Organisation { … } is a struct-or-union-specifier as specified in the C grammar at 6.7.2.1 1. The … part is a struct-declaration-list. The grammar for a struct-declaration-list shows that it is a list of struct-declaration items.
Inside this struct-declaration-list, we find the three “declarations” (“declarations” in quotes because they come from a different part of the grammar than the declaration in 6.7 1):
char organisation_name[20];

char org_number[20];

struct Employee 
{ 
    int employee_id; 
    char name[20]; 
    int salary; 
}; 

Each of these satisfies the grammar for a struct-declaration (which we may think of as “a form of declaration that may appear inside a structure,” not “a declaration of a structure”).
However, the constraint quoted above excludes the last of those, the struct Employee item. That code does not declare an anonymous structure or union (because it has a tag, the Employee in struct Employee, and 6.7.2.1 13 says an anonymous structure or union does not have a tag). So 6.7.2.1 2 says it must have a struct-declarator-list.1 Also shown in 6.7.2.1, a struct-declarator-list ether contains a declarator or is an unnamed bit-field (the form : constant-expression). Per 6.7.6 1, a declarator contains, somewhere in it, an identifier. (A declarator is an identifier with certain optional extra things: * for a pointer, brackets for an array, parentheses for function parameters, parentheses for grouping, and additional things associated with the aforementioned, such as array sizes and parameter types).
In other words, the standard requires each “declaration” that appears inside a structure definition to declare either an unnamed bit-field or a member name, either directly (like int x; or struct foo y;) or indirectly in an anonymous structure or union (like struct { int a, b; };). It excludes a “declaration” that does not add add a bit-field or named member to the structure (like int; or struct Employee;).

So, I'd like to know the logic behind it.

If there is a constraint violation in a program, then a compiler that conforms to the C standard must issue a diagnostic message.
However, the C standard is a voluntary specification. Nobody is required to obey it. “C” is not a trademark owned by a standards organization or anybody else. Generically, “C” is a family of languages or a rough idea of a language. So anybody is allowed to write a compiler that compiles something like what we know of as C and call it a C compiler, as long as they do not call it a standard-conforming C compiler.
Common C compilers have switches that adjust the ways in which they do or do not conform to the C standard. GCC by default does not conform to the C standard and allows a number of extensions to the standard. If you use the switches -std=c18 -pedantic, it will conform more closely to the standard, but there will still be variances.
Footnote
1 There is a bit of ambiguity in the English here. The struct Employee code does contain, nested inside of it, a struct-declarator-list because the definition of struct Employee contains nested “declarations” that have struct-declarator-list items. But 6.7.2.1 2 means a struct-declarator-list directly in the grammar rules in 6.7.2.1 1, not anything nested inside further grammar token replacements.

I’m taking very long time to understand, but it’s really helpful explanation based on clear sources. I appreciate your help!!
